# Error when installing Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: system-installation, 16.04

While installing Ubuntu this error message is shown. 
It says: "Unable to find the medium containing the live file system".

[image]

How can this problem be solved?

Comment: Do you have another USB flash drive /  hard drive plugged in ? If so, unplug it. Maybe try writing the Ubuntu ISO to the USB again.

Answer (score 0):

According to this post on the UbuntuForums "[initramfs) unable to find a medium containing a live file system.](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1850520)", you should try this:

> Change the SATA controller type from IDE to AHCI in Bios and everything works perfectly